# Can I access the $state outside of the active controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, angular-ui-router

I am writing an Angularjs app (using ui-router) based on the Hot Towel template.  The basic layout is a header area with navigation tabs and a dropdown list of users, and a content area below that.

The html looks basically like this:

```
<header>
   <div data-ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
</header>
<div ui-view></div>
```

I want my urls to be of the form **/:username/detail1**, **/:username/detail2**.  The idea is that you would select a user from the dropdown list and the content tabs would display information specific to the selected user.

**Problem:**

In the controller of my header, I need to know the current user so that I can select the appropriate item in the dropdown list, but I can't access the :username parameter.  $stateParams is empty.  I guess this makes sense because the docs say:

> the $stateParams object will only contain the params that were registered with that state.

and my header isn't associated with any particular state.  Still, having navigation controls in the header like this doesn't seem like some wacky edge case thing that I'm trying to do.  I know I can use $location to get the url and parse out the username, but that feels hacky.

Am I missing something obvious, or going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: What about using `$stateChangeStart` retrieve the `$stateParams`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `$state` and `$stateParams` to the `$rootScope` in the module run function like so:

```
angular.module('<module-name>').run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
  $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
});
```

That way you can access `$state` and `$stateParams` both in your template and in your controller because those items will be on every scope.

Comment: That doesn't work.  $rootScope.$stateParams has the same value as the $stateParams that is injected into my controller (which is to say that it's empty).